# Append a New Node in already existing XML Document

Tags: asp.net, xml

I want to append new node in already existing XML. My XML structure is as follows:-

```
<NewDataSet>
  <Table>
    <HotelName>A</HotelName>
    <Rating>5*</Rating>
    <Hzone>Central </Hzone>
    <HBeds>B</HBeds>
    <Address>Lodhi Road</Address>
    <Soh>-</Soh>
    <Recommended>0</Recommended>
    <DetailStr>-</DetailStr>
    <Block>N</Block>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <HotelName>B</HotelName>
    <Rating>5*</Rating>
    <Hzone>Central </Hzone>
    <HBeds>A</HBeds>
    <Address>Lodhi Road</Address>
    <Soh>Bh</Soh>
    <Recommended>0</Recommended>
    <DetailStr>-</DetailStr>
    <Block>N</Block>
  </Table>
<NewDataSet>
```

I want to add  node after  Tag i.e. I want my XML as

```
<NewDataSet>
  <Table>
    <HotelName>A</HotelName>
    <Rating>5*</Rating>
    <Hzone>Central </Hzone>
    <Address>Lodhi Road</Address>
    <HBeds>B</HBeds>
    <Soh>-</Soh>
    <Recommended>0</Recommended>
    <DetailStr>-</DetailStr>
    <Block>N</Block>
    <HId>1</HId>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <HotelName>B</HotelName>
    <Rating>5*</Rating>
    <Hzone>Central </Hzone>
    <Address>Lodhi Road</Address>
    <HBeds>A</HBeds>
    <Soh>Bh</Soh>
    <Recommended>0</Recommended>
    <DetailStr>-</DetailStr>
    <Block>N</Block>
    <HId>2</HId>
  </Table>
<NewDataSet>
```

I am getting the value of HId from Database using following code.

```
Dim XmlNodeListPackes As XmlNodeList
XmlNodeListPackes = xDoc.SelectNodes("/NewDataSet/Table") 
For Each xNode As XmlNode In XmlNodeListPackes

                Dim strHotelBeds As String = xNode.SelectSingleNode("Hbeds").InnerText
                Dim City As String = txtxmlfile.Text
                HId = DAL.GetHotelBedId(strHotelBeds, City)

            Next
```

I want to insert this HId in XML. Please help me with the code.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few things you should be aware of:

1. The Xml closing tag is missing `/`.
2. **Xml is case sensitive.** `<HBeds>` and `<Hbeds>` are different!

Here's an example how we can insert `<HId>` nodes as asked in the question.

In my Project I have the xml file, "MyXml.xml" :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<NewDataSet>
  <Table>
    <HotelName>A</HotelName>
    <Rating>5*</Rating>
    <Hzone>Central </Hzone>
    <HBeds>B</HBeds>
    <Address>Lodhi Road</Address>
    <Soh>-</Soh>
    <Recommended>0</Recommended>
    <DetailStr>-</DetailStr>
    <Block>N</Block>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <HotelName>B</HotelName>
    <Rating>5*</Rating>
    <Hzone>Central </Hzone>
    <HBeds>A</HBeds>
    <Address>Lodhi Road</Address>
    <Soh>Bh</Soh>
    <Recommended>0</Recommended>
    <DetailStr>-</DetailStr>
    <Block>N</Block>
  </Table>
</NewDataSet>
```

I have a test webform **WebForm1.aspx** with this markup:

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.vb" Inherits="VBXmlTest.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtxmlfile" runat="server">Vancouver</asp:TextBox>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

In the code behind, in `Page_Load` I am calling `ProcessXml` function, My **WebForm1.aspx.vb** is:

```
Imports System.Xml

Public Class WebForm1
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        ProcessXml()
    End Sub

    Private Sub ProcessXml()
        Dim xDoc As New XmlDocument
        Dim filePath As String = Server.MapPath("~/MyXml.xml")
        xDoc.Load(filePath)
        Dim XmlNodeListPackes As XmlNodeList
        XmlNodeListPackes = xDoc.SelectNodes("/NewDataSet/Table")
        Dim Hid As Integer
        For Each xNode As XmlNode In XmlNodeListPackes

            Dim strHotelBeds As String = xNode.SelectSingleNode("HBeds").InnerText
            Dim City As String = txtxmlfile.Text
            Hid = DAL.GetHotelBedId(strHotelBeds, City)
            Dim hidNode As XmlNode = xNode.SelectSingleNode("HId")
            If hidNode IsNot Nothing Then
                hidNode.InnerText = Hid
            Else
                hidNode = xDoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "HId", "")
                hidNode.InnerText = Hid
                xNode.AppendChild(hidNode)
            End If
        Next
        xDoc.Save(filePath)
    End Sub

End Class
```

And to test, I have replaced the DAL with a Module, just for testing:

```
Public Module DAL
    Public Function GetHotelBedId(ByVal strHotelBeds As String, ByVal City As String) As Integer
        Return 1
    End Function
End Module
```

And this is the output xml, no matter how many times I run it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<NewDataSet>
  <Table>
    <HotelName>A</HotelName>
    <Rating>5*</Rating>
    <Hzone>Central </Hzone>
    <HBeds>B</HBeds>
    <Address>Lodhi Road</Address>
    <Soh>-</Soh>
    <Recommended>0</Recommended>
    <DetailStr>-</DetailStr>
    <Block>N</Block>
    <HId>1</HId>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <HotelName>B</HotelName>
    <Rating>5*</Rating>
    <Hzone>Central </Hzone>
    <HBeds>A</HBeds>
    <Address>Lodhi Road</Address>
    <Soh>Bh</Soh>
    <Recommended>0</Recommended>
    <DetailStr>-</DetailStr>
    <Block>N</Block>
    <HId>1</HId>
  </Table>
</NewDataSet>
```

Answer (score 1):

Right after getting the HId value do this:

```
Dim xHIdNode = xNode.SelectSingleNode("HId")

If xHIdNode Is Nothing
    xHIdNode = xDoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "HId", Nothing)
    xNode.AppendChild(xNewNode)
End If

xHIdNode.Value = HId
```

That should do the job.

Comment: Showing Error:Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool.  This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached.

Comment: I suppose this exception comes from your DAL? Of course if it establishes a new connection for each and every time 'GetHotelBedId' is called then you most likely shouldn't call it in a for loop. I suggest you first loop through your XML document to collect the Hbeds data, then build a DAL query with it to fetch HId in a single db operation and THEN use the results to fill in your document.

Comment: Yes, it is coming from DAL. Then where should I use 'GetHotelBedId'. Everytime it is opening new connection.

Comment: I don't know your DAL specifics, you'll have to provide some code. However I suggest you create another question for that. What you asked here is how to create an XML node element, not how to fetch data from a database efficiently.

Comment: Sorry, I assumed you would call that loop only once. If not then indeed you must first check if the HId node already exists. I've edited my answer, have a look.